# Do <div>s pass usage context down to child elements

Tags: html, accessibility

I know that `div` elements don't have any semantic meaning, but do they pass down any usage context to their children? To put it another ways, are the following 2 examples **semantically** equivalent?

example 1:

```
<article>
  <div>
    <header></header>
  </div>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

example 2:

```
<article>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are identical in your example.

The only time a `<div>` will have any impact on semantics / accessibility are if you give it semantics via `aria` etc.

To reverse the answer, you can give any element the same semantic meaning as a `<div>` with `role="presentation"` (no semantic meaning).

For clarity in your examples the `<article>` element is the parent of the `<header>` and `<section>` elements as far as a screen reader is concerned. It may list the `<div>` in the accessibility tree but it will have no properties (so will be ignored).

You could nest 100 `<divs>` inside that element and a screen reader would treat it exactly the same (although there are good reasons not to do that obviously!)

> **As a "pure" container, the  element does not inherently represent
> anything.** Instead, it's used to group content so it can be easily
> styled using the class or id attributes, marking a section of a
> document as being written in a different language (using the lang
> attribute), and so on.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Comment: So regardless of how nested they are in divs, they will be passed down usage semantics? So if an HTML parsing tech, like a screen reader for example, was to go through this, it would be fair to expect it to read the `header` element as the header of the `article`, right?

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity, does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. So to put it another way, a semantic element operates under the context of the nearest semantic parent, right?

Comment: To "dumb it down" (take it to its simplest analogy) yes, obviously it acts on all related semantic elements. If you nest a `<h1>` in a `<section>` in an `<article>` within the `<main>` section all parts are considered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a page I can refer to for more information on exactly what we are talking about?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div talks about divs if that is what you mean? If you want information on semantics that is a vast topic so I don't think I could send you to one useful article on it.

Comment: Best bet would be to put a scenario together that you aren't sure how to structure the HTML / if there is a particular element you aren't sure where it should sit within a document etc. and let me / someone else answer in a different question. That would probably help narrow the field as to what you aren't sure about.

Comment: In the future `role="none"` will replace `role="presentation"`. And it makes sense if you ask me...

Comment: +1 Hrvoje.....but the problem is that assistive tech takes a looooooong time to catch up. I have built it into our system that role="presentation" is entered with [presentation] and run through a templating engine so that when this gets introduced and gets 95% coverage (our criteria for deciding whether to use a new technology) I can just change one variable and the whole site updates.